# Unable to set property "ctl.start"

Tags: java, android, vpn, pptp, l2tp

I am using [this](https://github.com/luojiesi/android-vpn-server) to configure and start `PPTP` or `L2TP` protocol programmatically

```
L2tpService l2tpService = new L2tpService();

VpnServiceBinder vpnServiceBinder = new VpnServiceBinder();

L2tpProfile l2tpProfile = new L2tpProfile();
l2tpProfile.setSecretEnabled(true);
l2tpProfile.setSecretString("123456");
l2tpProfile.setName("test");

l2tpService.setContext(vpnServiceBinder, l2tpProfile);

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), vpnServiceBinder.getClass());
startService(intent);
```

After run this code

```
l2tpService.connect("136.243.133.200", "test", "K@test");
```

Error:

> Unable to set property "ctl.start" to "mtpd": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)

Please help me.

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem?